# react Material-ui, How do I know I can use onClick for button?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The list of properties on the doc doesn't include `onClick` 
(http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/icon-button)

How do I know I need to use onClick for click handler?

Comment: What do you mean *How do I know I need to use onClick for click handler*?

Comment: You can use it just fine,but that's the least of your problems when using material ui with React.

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense Is there any known notoriety of material ui with react? I've just started doing my first project in react and using material ui everywhere possible, and now you're scaring me :|

Comment: @AsifMD Hmm... It's been over three years since I've used it so things might be different, but from what I remember, using something like `refs` was very difficult because you had to go through like 15 properties down a hierarchy to find their components and I kept breaking component encapsulation. The problem with that is `refs` are recommended for third-party dom elements. Just remember this was over 3 years ago so a lot could have changed.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

The Material-UI documentation does not list the standard React (native browser) events:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#mouse-events

This is because it's expected that you are already aware of the available native events. For example, you can also use `onWheel`. It would be a long and redundant list if all the native events were included.

As [kouak explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40167287/react-material-ui-how-do-i-know-i-can-use-onclick-for-button/40171419#40171419), other props (such as `onClick`) are passed down to a relevant child component.

Random example:

```
<Button color="primary" onClick={() => { console.log('onClick'); }}>
    Primary
</Button>
```

Answer (score 15):

You can add an wrapper over the `<IconButton/>` to get the `onClick` event.

Example

```
render() {
  return <div class="font-icon-wrapper" onClick={this.fontIconClick}>
    <IconButton iconClassName="muidocs-icon-custom-github" />
  </div>
}
```

This should definitely work...

Comment: The documentation would be much more useful if it showed the inheritance tree all the way back to the base class, with links to the documentation of each. A good example of what I mean is the way the Microsoft .NET Framework and MFC libraries are documented.

Comment: @DavidA.Gray you should submit an Issue to the project, it definitely would be nice to see the inheritance chain for a material UI class

Answer (score 13):

Remember, you can use onClick in every singe component that have a DOM renderer since it is a native React event (It doesn't have to be a button component).

Example 1:

```
<Paper
  className={classes.paper}
  onClick={() => {
    alert("✔️ This works on every component!");
  }}
>
  Click me!
</Paper>
```

---

Example 2:

[image: onClick possibilities]

⬇ Play with it online ⬇

[image: Edit onClick for every component]

Answer (score 5):

Just add `onClick` to the props you pass down into `<IconButton />`.

Props that are not cited in the doc are passed down into their internal `<EnhancedButton />` component which will handle `onClick` just fine.

See here : https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/IconButton/IconButton.js#L241

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 2):

## Handling clicks

All components accept an `onClick` handler that is applied to the root DOM element.

```
<Button onClick={() => { alert('clicked') }}>Click me</Button>
```

Note that the documentation avoids mentioning native props (there are a lot) in the API section of the components. [API for Button](https://material-ui.com/api/button/)

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

We should alway have to provide onClick event to parent because sometimes depends on browser, events might not work if we provided in to the child componet.

*Example:*

**Error:**

```
<TextField
    label={label}
    value={state.inputValue}
    InputProps={{
        endAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment position='end'>
                <IconButton style={{ padding: '3px' }}>
                    {state.inputValue?.length > 1 ? (
                        <ClearIcon onClick={handleClear}/>
                    ) : (
                        <DateRangeIcon onClick={onAdornmentClick}/>
                    )}
                </IconButton>
            </InputAdornment>
        ),
    }}
/>
```

**Solution:**

```
<TextField
    label={label}
    value={state.inputValue}
    InputProps={{
        endAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment position='end' onClick={state.inputValue?.length > 1 ? handleClear : onAdornmentClick}>
                <IconButton style={{ padding: '3px' }}>
                    {state.inputValue?.length > 1 ? (
                        <ClearIcon/>
                    ) : (
                        <DateRangeIcon/>
                    )}
                </IconButton>
            </InputAdornment>
        ),
    }}
/>
```